# Credential Provider V2 Combobox unexpected behavior

Tags: authentication, combobox, windows-10, winlogon, credential-providers

I've been developing our company's credential provider for windows 10 for almost a year now.

Now, I encountered a problem. I don't usually ask questions on forums, blogs, because in most cases I find the solution, but this time I've been struggling with an issue for a month now and I found the root of the problem.

Brief description of the problem itself: The credential provider uses a combobox, which worked before without a problem. Now, I rewrote the whole code to manage a big update, but a strange bug got into the system. The bug only occurs at a specific scenario. I'm developing and testing the code on my personal laptop.

The scenario:

1) The laptop is plugged in to my monitor / power, etc.

2) I make it go sleep.

3) I unplug all cables (including power).

4) I wake it up from sleep.

Than, the combobox doesn't show a default selected item, it's empty. When I drop it down, it shows all the necessary items. Than the credprov crashes and restarts, than everything is fine.

I know, that in similar "strange" scenarios, in most of the cases, a memory leak or something related causes the problem. When I check the event viewer it shows me c0000005, which is access violation. I started to debug where the violation is. Than I found out that the program refers the combobox item list array (actually vector in my case) at a very very high index (out of range could be the reason for the violation). The actual index is obviously stored in the "selectedComboItemIndex" variable (DWORD).

I was curious when did it change to this strange number, than I found an unexpected behavior.
The SetComboBoxSelectedValue method randomly gets called once (when the bug happens) with an insanely high index value. I don't even call this method in my code, so I have no idea, why does it get called. The call happens even when I don't drop down the combobox.

I give it a chance that it could be a bug in the credprov itself. What do you think? Have you seen this problem before?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does your provider loaded/unloaded during sleep/wakeup actions?

Comment: No, it does nothing else, but the official microsoft implementation of a V2 Credential Provider. So the LogonUI loads it and unloads it. I noticed after I wrote the question that not only this bug is the issue. The "SetSelected" method is called twice every time without calling the "SetDeselected" method. Again, I didn't touch anything on the user interface. It happens every time, not just when the described bug does.

Comment: Have your provider called for combo box item selection? In any case you must assume that the first item with index 0 is selected by default.

Comment: No. My provider doesn't call it from inside. It gets called by LogonUI only.

Comment: Have your provider been called by LogonUI for some of Combo Box methods after resume/wake-up?

Comment: No. It only can be called after it has been displayed on the screen. (SetSelected method).

Comment: What methods of your credential provider has been successfully called after wake-up and before crash? Inside of what method your provider are crashes?

Comment: It seems to me, that I partially solved the problem. I created a "filter" inside the SetSelected method. I declared a "selected" bool outside the method, and I only execute the SetSelected content when the "selected" bool is false. I set it to false when calling "SetDeselected" method and after calling "SetSelected" for the first time. Since I got this in the code, the strage bug didn't appear. I run more debugging and we'll see.

Comment: And to answer your question, all of the required methods ran successfully before the crash. Including the constructor, Initialize, SetSelected and the methods that I call from any of the three functions.

Comment: Nice to read good news!

Comment: Just now, the SetSelected inner code didn't run, despite it hasn't been called before. Maybe something violates the memory and rewrote the bool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by stopping to use "SetSelected" and "SetDeselected" methods. Furthermore, I filtered the "SetComboBoxSelectedValue" input parameters to accept valid numbers only. When the index parameter is invalid, I recall the same method with the index parameter replaced to the first item (0).